# How to interpret an integral with the measure as the basis of an indicator?

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

How do I interpret such an integral: $$ \int \mathbb{}_{dx}(x)f(x)$$
Am I correct thinking that it is a function of $x'$, and equal to:
$$ \int f(x) \delta_{x'}(dx) = f(x') ~~~~?$$